# Understanding how to pull info from array

Tags: javascript

I have a previously created script that is doing API calls to get various info. Using json fetch. Its used to look up(GET) properties of users, groups, etc.

Here is how it prints. `console.log(myArray)`:

[{user={conversion_id=smitht, ship_id=14.0, ship=Mountain , id=989, name=Smith, Todd, id=8745335.0, system_id=796663, login_id=todd.smith@domain.com,, created_at=3055-08-10, //keeps continuing for all users in this account

If I wanted to search the array and return only "name". Is there a better way to accomplish than this? This will print out just the names

```
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  console.log(myArray[i]['user']['name'])
```

I'm trying to learn what's possible and how to interact. Any other options to search through array? Most examples have sample arrays written out since mine comes from a response its been difficult to follow those examples.

Comment: That's invalid JSON. `[{user=`?

Answer (score 0):

use `find` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
function findByLoginId(loginId) {
      const result = myArray.find(user => user.login_id === loginId);
      return result?.name;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the JSON is not valid.

Comment: @Andy yes but if he can log user names by `console.log(myArray[i]['user']['name'])` then it valid json

Comment: The OP says that code will output the names (and they're not wrong). The OP never says that they're actually _using_ that code on the invalid data they've received from the API.

Comment: @Andy I dont think I have any invalid data because above if I print the response, I get array above. It contains all users for a specified group. I want to just pull the names of all users in that group

Comment: @Mr.Anderson the response is meant to be JSON. What you're getting from the server is __not__ JSON. You can't parse a non-JSON to a JS object/array using `JSON.parse`. It. just. won't. work.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the fetched data is valid JSON. You should be able to use JSON.parse on the returned data.

Comment: Yes that is in the function which has url and fetch. let response = JSON.parse(fetch

Comment: I think this answer should include some hints how to validate JSON.